# libbpf load ebpf error -22: rodata is referenced but wasn't created

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, ebpf

I wrote a simple eBPF program,
but got a weird error when bpf_program__load with libbpf

```
libbpf: prog 'PreOpen': BPF program load failed: Invalid argument
libbpf: prog 'PreOpen': -- BEGIN PROG LOAD LOG --
0: <invalid BPF map reference>
BPF map 'tmp.rodata' is referenced but wasn't created
```

Here is the full code:

```
struct syscalls_enter_args {
    __u64 unused;
    __u64 syscall_nr;
    __u64 args[6];
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_openat")
int PreOpen(struct syscalls_enter_args *ctx){
    bpf_printk("testing");
}

char _license[] SEC("license")="GPL";
```

I only call bpf_printk to print testing message
when the kernel hit the hook point
sys_pre_openat